# How to split key pair equal value from string?

Tags: javascript

Here is my response string

> var resp = "atoken  # #Wed Oct 02 03:24:09 PDT 2013
>   AUTHTOKEN=1a26625dfcc94fb07eacd4a77c7595ee RESULT=TRUE";

I would like take value by key of `AUTHTOKEN`.

Comment: If it is you, who generates the response, use `JSON` for that purpose.

Comment: Split on lines, split on blanks, split on equal signs, and then find the pair with the key `AUTHTOKEN`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a regex

```
resp.match(/.* (AUTHTOKEN=(.*)) .*/);
var authToken= RegExp.$2;
```

my match is a bit overkill though

**EDIT** Explanation of Regexp in JS

The regular expression above utilizes groups (identified by parens).  When a regular expression is executed on a match, the RegExp class retains the groups of the last execution. Group 1, group 2, etc etc.

In the above case the expression will produce the following groups

Group 1: AUTHTOKEN=1a26625dfcc94fb07eacd4a77c7595ee
Group 2: 1a26625dfcc94fb07eacd4a77c7595ee

Hypothetically, I could have used the expression

```
/.* AUTHTOKEN=(.*) .*/
```

Which would have put the match of the execution in RegExp.$1

[This article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) will give you much more information than I can provide here about JavaScript and regular expressions.

Comment: +1 will you please explain how RegExp as a Class have a property like $2 related to the resp where is the link here ?

Comment: The leading `.*` is not necessary.  The trailing `.*` is only necessary so that `RESULT=true` is not included in the match array.

Answer (score 1):

This one doesn't use regular expression and it uses [Array.every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) method.

```
var resp = "atoken # #Wed Oct 02 03:24:09 PDT 2013 AUTHTOKEN=1a26625dfcc94fb07eacd4a77c7595ee RESULT=TRUE", token;
resp.split(" ").every(function(currentValue) {
    var pair = currentValue.split("=");
    if (pair.length === 2) {
        if (pair[0] === "AUTHTOKEN") {
            token = pair[1];
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
});

console.log(token);
```

**Output**

```
1a26625dfcc94fb07eacd4a77c7595ee
```

**EDIT:**

For this case, on my machine, RegEx solution performs well. http://jsperf.com/search-in-key-value-pairs